# Getting undefined when I expect otherwise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

if you take a look at the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6eb23917/), you will see that I have created a class called: `EventHandler` which I then use as below (and in the fiddle):

```
/**
 * Event Handler Class
 */
class EventHandler {

  /**
   * Core constructor.
   */
  constructor() {
    this.events       = [];
    this.beforeEvents = [];
    this.afterEvents  = [];
  }

  /**
   * Register an event.
   *
   * @param {string} name
   * @param {cb} callback
   */
  register(name, cb) {
    const event = {
      name: name,
      cb: cb
    }

    this.events.push(event);
  }

  /**
   * Trigger an event based on name.
   *
   * @param {string} name
   * @return {various}
   */
  trigger(name) {
    this.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event.name === name) {
        return event.cb();
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * Get only the events.
   *
   * @return {array} events
   */
  getEvents() {
    return this.events;
  }
}

const eventHandler = new EventHandler();
eventHandler.register('hello.world', () => {
    return 'hello world';
});

alert(eventHandler.trigger('hello.world'));
```

When you run the fiddle, you get `undefined`, I expect to see `'hello world'`.

**Ideas?**

Comment: What is the expected result if there are two handlers registered?

Answer (score 3):

In the `trigger` function you are returning undefined. Returning from inside a `forEach` callback does not return the parent function.

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
trigger(name) {
    let msg = '';
    this.events.forEach((event) => {
        if (event.name === name) {
            msg = event.cb();
        }
    });
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're `alert`ing the response of `eventHandler.trigger` which doesn't actually return anything, hence the `undefined`. You could use something like `Array.prototype.find` to get find your event and then return the callbacks response like so:

```
trigger(name) {
    let event = this.events.find(e => e.name === name);

    if (event)
        return e.cb();

    return null;
}
```

A better method would be to store a key => value pair of event and callbacks, this way you won't have to find, you could just do something like:

```
trigger(event) {
    return this.events[event] ? this.events[event]() : null;
}
```